# How to manage assigning ID to hidden field for multiple rows?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables, asp.net-ajax, hidden-field

I have an array of more than a hundred records which I have returned via Ajax response from the database with values like Id, First Name, Last Name, and Email. I have assigned the last three fields (First Name, Last Name, and Email) to the Data Table rows in my Razor View each with action buttons in the last column. For the sake of simplicity, I want to assign the Id value to a hidden field so that I can manage to edit a specific row easily with the help of that row's specific Id.

Although I have a hidden field on my Razor View, I am wondering how I should assign the Id value to that hidden field for each record? My code looks like the following:

```
var userTable;
$.ajax({
        url: serviceUrl + "/api/account/getallusers",
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (res) {
            var strHTML = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

                strHTML += '<tr>';
                strHTML += '<td style="width: 20px !important;">';
                strHTML += res[i].FirstName;
                strHTML += '</td>';
                strHTML += '<td style="width: 30px !important;">';
                strHTML += res[i].LastName;
                strHTML += '</td>';
                strHTML += '<td style="width: 50px !important;">';
                strHTML += res[i].Email;
                strHTML += '</td>';
                strHTML += '<td>';

                //Code for action buttons goes here

                strHTML += '</td>';
                strHTML += '</tr>';
            }

            $('#dtusers tbody').html(strHTML);
                userTable = $("#dtusers").DataTable({
            });

    });
```

Is there any simple yet effective way to assign the Id value to a hidden field so that it can serve me well during edit operation?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly then you could do this by adding a counter variable before your for loop. Then you could add this to ID of your TR element within the table.

Something like

```
strHTML += '<TR id=tableRow' + counter + '>';
```

Then at the end of the for loop increment your counter for the next iteration.

Whether it is hidden or not makes no difference since anyone that uses developer tools can still see the values of attributes within elements.

Your code would look something like this

```
var userTable;
 $.ajax({
    url: serviceUrl + "/api/account/getallusers",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (res) {
        var strHTML = "";
        var counter = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

            strHTML += '<tr id=tableRow' + counter + '>';
            strHTML += '<td style="width: 20px !important;">';
            strHTML += res[i].FirstName;
            strHTML += '</td>';
            strHTML += '<td style="width: 30px !important;">';
            strHTML += res[i].LastName;
            strHTML += '</td>';
            strHTML += '<td style="width: 50px !important;">';
            strHTML += res[i].Email;
            strHTML += '</td>';
            strHTML += '<td>';

            //Code for action buttons goes here

            strHTML += '</td>';
            strHTML += '</tr>';
            counter++; //increment the counter for next iteration
        }

        $('#dtusers tbody').html(strHTML);
            userTable = $("#dtusers").DataTable({
        });

});
```

Comment: how may I manage to maintain the hidden field for each iteration of the loof? May I have to use the same hidden field? Because the records I have in Ajax response are too much even they might be countless.

Comment: What about assigning the Id value (returned from the database via Ajax response) to the id of each specific row? Isn't this the best alternative as compare to counter variable? Because I need the Id to be assigned somehow to each tr.

Comment: I agree, you could also query for the index in the table and assign that instead of a counter variable. In this case you need to edit your SQL query to also return the record ID which you can then assign as the ID of the table row. You would do it like this strHTML += '<tr id=tableRow' + res[i].rowID+ '>';

Comment: I agree with this, I have also applied the same techniques but not the best approach. I think I must stick to the hidden field but I must look for some dynamic techniques that can help me assign the id column of each row to a hidden field. I'm in fact not sure either I have to manage this with just a single hidden field or I may need multiple?

Comment: One ID is enough to later on use something like querySelectorAll() to retrieve all values within the rows. I don't see the reason why you would need a hidden field for that since you can use any attribute you want to grab data, the ID of each tableRow in this case.